# What kind of model is used by 20 Questions?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, neural-networks, references

Which kind of machine learning concept / model is used in [20 Questions](http://www.20q.net)?
Is this kind of thing best solved by a neural network?
Where I can read something about it?

Comment: No idea but I'd guess decision trees.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm not sure if you'll get an answer.

Comment: @gung: why? there are more possible answers? what can we do to maximize the change of getting an answer?

Comment: You can find (often surprisingly simple) programs for this kind of thing. They generally just keep a tree of questions and responses, which can be updated as people try new things it couldn't guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you might want to read up on how IBM pulled off the Watson prep for the [Jeapardy game show appearance](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/ibm-watson-the-inside-story-of-how-the-jeopardy-winning-supercomputer-was-born-and-what-it-wants-to-do-next/). That seams to be a problem of similar (huge) scope. The researches at IBM at first stated, ""They initially said no, it's a silly project to work on, it's too gimmicky, it's not a real computer science test, and we probably can't do it anyway."

I would guess that you would use some kind of entropy or information gain model, similar to a decision tree, for question choice. Then the answer would somehow have to be integrated into an existing knowledge model to iterate with. However, a full treatment of this would probably require Ph.D. level knowledge and the writing of a book.

Comment: I've tried to google for it and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887533/how-do-20-questions-ai-algorithms-work